# Conversion of a pipe delimited text file to xls

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert a text file to xls format but the conversion does not seem to work.
Although the filename is .csv, the data in the file is actually pipe delimited
When opened in Excel, the converted file shows text like in 1 column with delimiters not removed.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Folder = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    CurrentDate = Format(Date, "MM-dd-yyyy")

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Folder & "\marginRiskSummary631_" & CurrentDate & ".csv", Delimiter:="|", Format:=6
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Folder & "\GS_marginRiskSummary631.xls", FileFormat:=56, CreateBackup:=False, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
    ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
End Sub
```

Can someone please help me to do the conversion properly.

Comment: I think Excel is dumb when it sees ".csv" and loses it's head ignoring everything else you are telling it. You could try renaming the file to ".txt" or, alternatively, run a text-to-column after importing.

Comment: You can automate text-to-column. Just run `Sheet1.Range("A:A").TextToColumns()` filling out the parameters for this particular situation. That might be the easiest solution to this one.

Comment: Record a macro while opening the file in excel using `Data >> From text` that should give you what you need.

Comment: If you give the file a ".CSV" extension, then Excel will look for commas as the delimiters... Can you edit the source file so it has commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue some times ago. After searching I came to the following solution

When I can, I rename the file and change its extension to ".txt" and then it works with the code you have posted.
If I cannot rename, then I use the below code to do the conversion (just after the workbook.open method)

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :="|"
```

It does the job usually. Hope this helps.

Comment: I got it to work by renaming the .csv file to .dat thanks @Dan